# Generating Function of 'Vandermonde Identity' Like Coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I wish to simplify the following generating function:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j = 0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{n - k}{m - j}x^j.
$$
Note that Vandermonde's identity tells us that:
$$
f(1) = \sum_{j = 0}^k\binom{k}{j}\binom{n - k}{m - j} = \binom{n}{m}.
$$
Hence, the title! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? Also, out of curiosity: where did this generating function come from, *what does it count*?

Comment: By simplify, I mean express in terms of some well-known series. Similar to how one would 'simplify' $f(x) = \sum_{j \geq 0} x^j$ as $\frac{1}{1 - x}$.

Comment: @Ameya: Ah: you mean *find a closed form for $f$*.

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: What is $K$ in the summation bound?

Comment: Sorry, changed to $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)$ as $f_m(x)$ to indicate the dependence on $m$. By binomial theorem, we see that $f_m(x)$ is the coefficient of $y^m$ in the product
$$
(1+xy)^k (1+y)^{n-k}.$$

Hence, we are able to write a generating function
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f_m(x) y^m = (1+xy)^k(1+y)^{n-k}.
$$

To find $f_m(x)$ from this, take $m$-th derivative of the RHS and put $y=0$. Then we have
$$
m! f_m(x) = \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial y}\right)^m (1+xy)^k(1+y)^{n-k} \Bigg\vert_{y=0}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This is closer to what I need.